# How to scale a Gantt figure?

Tags: floats, scaling, pgfgantt

**Sketch:**

I was trying to scale a [Gantt chart](http://www.martin-kumm.de/tex_gantt_package.php) in order to fit in to a Beamer presentation.

Suppose I have some gantt chart bigger than the presentation rectangle:

```
 \begin{figure}
   \begin{gantt}{20}{20}
     \begin{ganttitle}
       \numtitle{2012}{1}{2016}{4}
     \end{ganttitle}

     %% lots of activities
     \ganttbar{1}{0}{3}
     ...
     ...
     \ganttbar{1}{0}{19}
     %% lots of activities
   \end{gantt}
 \end{figure}
```

**Question:**
How can I scale this figure to fix in a beamer frame?

**Example:**
If I was using some PNG image, surely I will make this:

```
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphic[scale=0.5]{mypngpic.png}
\end{figure}
```

But in gantt environment there is no *(at least I don't know yet)* a way to scale.

Answer (score 7):

Since the `gantt` is based on TikZ, forcing the scale externally also works. I didn't check the code carefully but maybe there is a possibility to supply the options directly to the `gantt` environment. It has it's own key system but it didn't recognize the scale options.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gantt}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={yscale=0.3,transform shape}}
   \begin{gantt}{5}{12}
     \begin{ganttitle}
       \numtitle{2012}{1}{2014}{4}
     \end{ganttitle}
     %% lots of activities
     \ganttbar{1}{0}{3}
     \ganttbar{1}{0}{10}
     %% lots of activities
   \end{gantt}

\tikzset{every picture/.style={yscale=1,transform shape}}
   \begin{gantt}{5}{12}
     \begin{ganttitle}
       \numtitle{2012}{1}{2014}{4}
     \end{ganttitle}
     %% lots of activities
     \ganttbar{1}{0}{3}
     \ganttbar{1}{0}{10}
     %% lots of activities
   \end{gantt}

\end{document}
```

[image]
Note also that there is another TikZ based package [`pgfgantt`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfgantt).

Comment: There's `xunitlengt` for the `x` component, but unfortunately I didn't see a `y` analogous.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Indeed. There is an additional `ganttx` option hook but I don't know what it's for.

Answer (score 6):

Put the contents between `\begin{gantt}{20}{20}......\end{gantt}` in a file, say `myganttfig1.tex`. Then in your main tex file use `\resizebox` like:

```
%=========================
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering{
\resizebox{0.62\textwidth}{!}{\input{myganttfig1.tex}}}
\caption{your caption \label{fig:mygantt1}
\end{figure}
%===========================
```

You may change the width `0.62\textwidth` and height `!` to suit your needs. The parameter `{!}` ensures that the height is decided keeping the aspect ratio intact.

As Gonzalo observes in his comments, in this particular case, it will be more suitable to use both height and width.